# Can you tell how to make a update in DB, with fileupload (File is updated ok)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

Can you tell how to make a update in DB, using fileupload (File is updated ok) ?

I dont get any errors message, but the edit controller make a new row in DB, instead of updating the old row.

I have tried to remove insertOnsubmit, but only result is no update at all, in DB

I'am using LINQ to SQL MVC4

Table  id - CompanyNameCon  -  PdfCon

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        DAT_SupplyCon SupplyCon = db.DAT_SupplyCons.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (SupplyCon == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(SupplyCon);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Books/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(DAT_SupplyCon DAT_SupplyCon, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Delete old file
            FileUpload.DeleteFile(DAT_SupplyCon.PdfCon);



            // Upload our file
            DAT_SupplyCon.PdfCon = FileUpload.UploadFile(file);
  ????      db.DAT_SupplyCons.InsertOnSubmit(DAT_SupplyCon);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(DAT_SupplyCon);
    }
```

view

```
@model CFire2.Models.DAT_SupplyCon

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}


<h2>Edit</h2>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "SupplyCon", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-   data" }))
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>DAT_SupplyCon</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierCon)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupplierCon)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierCon)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyNameCon)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyNameCon)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyNameCon)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PdfCon)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PdfCon)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PdfCon)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Utils:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;


namespace CFire2.Utils
{
public static class FileUpload
{

public static char DirSeparator =
System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
public static string FilesPath = "Content" +
DirSeparator + "Uploads" + DirSeparator;
public static string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

   if (null == file) return "";

   if (!(file.ContentLength > 0)) return "";
   string fileName = file.FileName;
   string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);


   if (null == fileExt) return "";

   if (!Directory.Exists(FilesPath))
   {

      Directory.CreateDirectory(FilesPath);
   }

     var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/SupplyCon"),fileName);

   file.SaveAs(Path);

   return fileName;
}
public static void DeleteFile(string fileName)
{

   if (fileName.Length == 0) return;

   var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/SupplyCon"), fileName);

   if (File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(path)))
   {

       File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath(path));
   }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden field for your primary key property to your form.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
```

Otherwise it'll be treated as a new record since no primary key is posted.

Comment: Hi dombenoit, I have made a Edit view, like you suggest, but it still makes a new row, with a new Primary Key.  I have also made a Edit view, where the primary is not hidden. When the view opens it is the old ID, but when I hit "Save" it makes a new row with a new ID

Comment: That would be because your code is executing an insert : `db.DAT_SupplyCons.InsertOnSubmit(DAT_SupplyCon);`. You need to change that to : `db.Entry(DAT_SupplyCon).State = EntityState.Modified;`.

Comment: Hi Again, it will not accept Entry (I think together with LINQ to SQL) Error no definition for "entry"

Answer (score 0):

InsertOnSubmit method work on the basis of primary key .
if primary key value is not exists in DB it will create a new record otherwise it will update that record .

In your case you can use hidden field to store the primary key id into the model .
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PrimaryKeyID)

Comment: Hi Atul, I have made a Edit view, like you suggest, but it still makes a new row, with a new Primary Key.  I have also made a Edit view, where the primary is not hidden. When the view opens it is the old ID, but when I hit "Save" it makes a new row with a new ID